# Dynamic headers that are recalculated with each retry

Tags: angular5, rxjs5, angular-httpclient

I have an AuthenticatedHttpClient class which extends HttpClient and all my services make use of this so that each request that is made provides a JWT token to the API.

I've also got a generic error handler that handles a 401 response when the token expires, and refreshes the token with a refresh token, then should replay the original request, so it appears seamless (baring a slight increase in delay).

This is all working fine, except that the replayed requests have the original headers in them that were set at the time it was created, and so they JWT token in the headers is now out of date.

I can come up with two solutions...

1) somehow edit the request on retry and alter the headers to use the current token

2) (preferred) make the requests retrieve the token at the time they are sent, rather than when they are created.

I don't know how to do either currently...  If someone can tell me the solution to either I'd greatly appreciate it...

Example use of retry mechanics in my AuthenticatedHttpClient:

```
public get<T>(endPoint: string, options?: IRequestOptions): Observable<T> {
    console.log('my http client requesting Get');
    return this.http.get<T>(endPoint, options).retryWhen(this.handleErrorAndRetry(this.authService));
}
```

handleErrorAndRetry definition:

```
private handleErrorAndRetry(authService: AuthenticationService): (error: any) => any {
  return (error: any) => {
    return error
      .flatMap((err: any) => {
        if (err.status === 401) {
          return authService.refreshTokenObservable()
        }
        return Observable.throw({error: 'No retry'});
      })
      .take(2);
  };
}
```

Example use of AuthenticatedHttpClient in a service:

```
listEntities(companyId: any): Observable<Entity[]> {
    return this.http.get<Entity[]>(`${this.apiBase}/${this.apiResource}/${companyId}/${this.apiSubResource}`, {
        headers: this.getHeaders()
    });
}
```

Comment: I believe you should explore [Http Interceptor](https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses)